# Flutter native code - invoking platform channel in separate isolate

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to add native code to my flutter application which basically just have 2 methods to play and stop alarm. I added native code in android in MainActivity and dart but I am getting exception:
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method playAlarm on channel com.example.smart_alarm/android_ring_manager)

Already tried:

(i). Uninstalling/reinstalling app

(ii). flutter clean and flutter run

(iii). Changing the channel names

'''

```
private static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "com.example.smart_alarm/android_ring_manager";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

    startService(new Intent(this, AlarmRingerService.class));

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL_NAME).setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
        if (call.method.equals("playAlarm")) {
            System.out.println("MainActivity: Playing alarm");
            AlarmRingerService.playAlarm();
            result.success(null);
        } else if (call.method.equals("stopAlarm")) {
            System.out.println("MainActivity: Stopping alarm");
            AlarmRingerService.stopAlarm();
            result.success(null);
        }
    });
}
```

```
Flutter dart code: This is executed from alarm callback in separate isolate

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class AlarmRingManager {
  static const MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('com.example.smart_alarm/android_ring_manager');

  static Future<void> playAlarm() async {
    try {
      await _channel.invokeMethod('playAlarm');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Unable to call play alarm on platform channel $e');
    }
  }

  static Future<void> stopAlarm() async {
    try {
      await _channel.invokeMethod('stopAlarm');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Unable to call stop alarm on platform channel $e');
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Do I need to to register my method call handler somewhere else or in manifest?

----------- Edit- -----------------------------------------------

So I debugged it more and figured out that the issue is not with platform channel callback. The problem was I was invoking the platform channel method from android_alarm_manager callback. Since android_alarm_manager runs in a different isolate and method call handler was set in main isolate, hence it was not able to find it.

Is there a way I can define platform channel in android BE service so that it is always available to all isolates? I can see it working if I use it for existing plugins but I am not sure how to add my own code so that native platform channel is available to all isolates.

Comment: are you sure that `CHANNEL_NAME` is correct? ("com.example.smart_alarm/android_ring_manager")

Comment: I thought I can give it any channel name?
I am constructing channel name from my app package_name/android_ring_manager. I also tried just giving it android_ring_manager.

Oh if you meant that it matches dart code, yes it does. I added the private static const line

Comment: does [platform_channel](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_channel) example work at you? it is located at `<flutter_root>/examples` folder

Comment: Let me try that. But other platform channels are still working (other packages which I have included in my project)

Comment: Alright tested this. This one works, still no idea why. Let me try and diff

Comment: yes diff: good idea

Comment: or add some extra logging, for example add `Log.d` before `if (call.method.equals("playAlarm")) {`

Comment: I had some logging there and in fact I had else {} case as well, but program control doesn't reach there.

Comment: what `else {}`? i dont see any `else {}` in your code

Comment: I changed the code to reflect original with some logging. I tried this
new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL_NAME).setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
       System.out.println("In method call handler");
       result.success(null);
    });

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I am posting this Answer Flutter does not support calling Native channel call on from Isolates.

Please check: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937

Alternatively there are some promising Plugins like: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate

But they come with their own complications of Invoking secondary FlutterEngine and running calls over them.