# Flutter - invoking method in method channel from a different isolate

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates, huawei-location-kit

I am using [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task) to spawn a foreground service which calls a [library to fetch location](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-flutter-plugin/tree/master/flutter-hms-location) that invokes native code tru the use of method channels. However I am getting this error (it works perfectly when being called from the app/main isolate):

`MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getLastLocation on channel com.huawei.flutter.location/fusedlocation_methodchannel)`

I saw this similar problem on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798544/flutter-native-code-invoking-platform-channel-in-separate-isolate), however the native code is coming from a library, and I don't want to modify the library as much as possible.

I also saw [this article](https://medium.com/flutter/introducing-background-isolate-channels-7a299609cad8) that Flutter 3.7 already supports calling natively from background isolate channels, but I'm already updated to Flutter 3.13.6. (Or is this not related to my issue?)

### Questions

- How to invoke a method from a different isolate without modifying the library
- How to initialize Flutter Plugins programmatically, since I'm thinking if I can initialize the library on the foreground service
- Is there any other workaround to solve this?

**EDIT:**
Here's how I use the library, the `startCallback` is the entry point (and I assume this is separated from main isolate)

```
await FlutterForegroundTask.startService(
  notificationTitle: _environmentVariables.appName,
  notificationText: Il8n.current.foregroundTaskMessage,
  callback: startCallback,
);

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void startCallback() {
  // wait for pre requisite before initializing foreground service scope
  // ignore: prefer-async-await
  ServiceLocator.registerPrerequisiteDependencies().then((_) {
    initForegroundServiceScope(ServiceLocator.instance);

    FlutterForegroundTask.setTaskHandler(
      MyOwnTaskHandler(), // this needed by the library, invoking functions from the foreground service
    );
  });
}
```

And this is how I use the [Huawei's library to get location (which uses method channels upon checking their library)](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-flutter-plugin/tree/master/flutter-hms-location):

```
final locationService = FusedLocationProviderClient();

final location = await locationService.getLastLocation(); // this is working on main isolate, but not on the foreground service
```

Comment: @pskink sorry but can you explain the point of running this, I also updated that it is working fine when calling it from the main app.

Comment: did you notice that `invokeMethod` is called from non main isolate?

Comment: @pskink It is working properly, and shows the copied text from clipboard. Am I looking at this incorrectly? I know we're trying to invoke method on a non main isolate to test if it will work, but I'm not sure if this is the same problem I'm encountering when the library declares how it invokes the method.

Why is it working on main isolate, and why it is not when not on main isolate using the Huawei's library, when I'm using the exact same function?

Comment: now that your current flutter version can invoke native method channels from non main isolate then post your not working code, without it, it's really hard to say anything

Comment: @pskink I supplied the basic code, I didn't add it because I don't think it will help as I'm using libraries for foreground service (this is the non main isolate), and the Huawei location (this is the method channel). From what I searched also, this is a common problem across libraries where in the method channel from a library is not working if called from a separate isolate.

Comment: tried to call `BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized(token)`? when calling method channel from non UI isolate it seemed to be required to call it

Comment: I compare the library that I'm using for Google devices and it seems that it is also using `MethodChannel` (https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator), but it is working. So I think the problem is the Huawei library itself. I also found that there's this `dartPluginClass` in their `pubspec.yaml`, but I'm not sure but it contributes to this issue.